# Do I require a dongle for the Xbox 360?

Tags: guitar-hero-series

For a Guitar Hero game on the Xbox 360, do I require a Dongle like the PS2/PS3 to use a Guitar Hero Wireless Guitar?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. The Guitar Hero controllers for Xbox 360 are wireless, naturally. They will connect to the console in the same fashion that a wireless Xbox 360 controller will.

That said, from what I have seen, PlayStation 3 Guitar Hero controllers operate in the same way; they also do not need a dongle.

Comment: Then is this false? http://www.amazon.com/Guitar-World-Receiver-Dongle-Playstation-3/dp/B002EE6T1E/ref=sr_1_2?s=videogames&ie=UTF8&qid=1451359070&sr=1-2&keywords=usb+dongle+ps3

Comment: No, but its also not a wireless receiver. Think of it this way, why would they make a dongle to use wireless, when the console can already use wireless? That appears to be a wired dongle (you can tell by the usb interfaces on **both** ends). I would wager that its primary function is to allow you to connect controllers released for the earlier games, on PlayStation 2.